# Trying to make the program wait for a number of seconds and then continuing in C# using Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was writing some code to make an AI shoot forwards but the AI shoots so fast that it will hit it's own bullets and they will explode. I have tried to add a delay in between but I do not know how to do it. Here is the part of my code in which I need it. Please help, thanks!

```
private void Start()
{
    m_FireButton = "Fire" + m_PlayerNumber;

    m_ChargeSpeed = (m_MaxLaunchForce - m_MinLaunchForce) / m_MaxChargeTime;
}

void OnTriggerStay(Collider other) {
    if (other.tag == "Player")  {
        Fire ();
        //This is where I want to add a delay!
    }
}
```

Comment: It is just not working, could you please show me how to set it up. I am still a bit new to c# and unity. This is why I came here

Comment: You are using "stay" rather then "enter", it's that simple. **But you need to learn about the simple `Invoke` call in Unity.**  Never, ever use coroutines for any reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to happen properly you need to think why it fails. The reason is that OnTriggerStay is called for each FixedUpdate the player is within the collider.

What you want is a different approach.

```
private bool isInside = false;
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col){
    if(col.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") == false){ return; }
    isInside = true;
    Fire();
}
void OnTriggerExit(Collider col){
    if(col.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") == false){ return; }
    isInside = false;
    timer  = 0f;
}
private float timer = 0f;
private float waitTime = 0.2f;
void Update(){
    if(isInside == false) { return; }
    if(timer > waitTime){
        timer = 0f;
        Fire();
    }
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: This is a link to the whole file with the code. https://gist.github.com/alexo1001/f371e6a2e17f4d492c3d

Comment: Create a new script, you should not mix shooting and movement, those are separated actions. What is above is pretty much the whole code. Just move the Fire method to that new script.

Comment: Should I click "Ok" when it says: "API update required"? Probably yes.

Comment: That does not seem to be related. But yes.

Comment: Bro, thank you SOOO MUCH. It has some small bugs but I think I will be able to fix them. This is why I love Stackoverflow! You ask a question and you get an answer immediately.

Comment: hi @alexo1001 - well done for TICKING AN ANSWER.  All new users need to TICK ANSWERS on this site.

Comment: for providing a solution that isn't coroutine-based you get a +1